# Formatting floating point numbers in ASP

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

A friend asked me to update his shopping cart software. It's written in classical ASP using IE's JScript. I can't seem to format the variables correctly.

```
. <% if (oOrder['product'] == "camera") 
{ %> <%= format_float(oOrder['cost'], 2, 3)/2 %> <% } %> 
                                    %>
```

When I do this I get a bunch of jibberish with regards to the output. I'm guessing it's because of a datatype mismatch.

I get `-1.#IND` as the output.

Comment: Sorry about the formatting when I put the code in the whole thing became invisible

Comment: @steve: I've added te code foramtting for you. Care to share what is the output?

Comment: Isn't the equality operator = in classic ASP?  And how are you using curly brackets?

Comment: Classic ASP will let you use JScript and/or VBScript on the server side. If you use the JScript on the server you can get all your curly bracket goodness, use == etc. Sadly there's a lot of confusion because JScript also refers to a bastardized version of JavaScript that runs client-side in IE.

Comment: @steve: could you give us a little more context for the code? Like if there's a check to make sure that `oOrder['cost']` is a number, what `format_float()` is trying to do, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What does format_float do, and what does it return?  I suspect it is returning a formatted string, in which case you need to divide first, like this:

```
<%= format_float(oOrder['cost']/2, 2, 3) %>
```

But you still need a way to parse oOrder['cost'] if it is a string and format_float is not doing it.

Comment: @Robert: I didn't know classic ASP 1/2.0 support server-side jscript, so you really think it's the `format_float` causing the problem and not the entire syntax?

Comment: Is that what this is, jscript?  I haven't a clue about jscript.

Comment: Classic ASP rides on top of VBScript (at least the syntax is), seeing `[ ] { } ==` on a ASP server-side script really confuses me.

Comment: Don't be confused, JScript for ASP is IMHO a far better language to use. Its structured and so much nicer to write and read when done well :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is how the code ought to be structured:-

```
<%
   if (oOrder.product == "camera")
   {
      Response.Write(format_float(order.cost / 2, 2, 3)); 
   }
%>
```

Try to avoid closing and opening default script tags `%> <%` when you have no actual HTML markup inbetween.

Comment: @AnonJr: Robert has already provided the answer.  Didn't seem much point repeating it.

Comment: Sorry, too much blood in my caffeine system... Didn't notice that you used the code from Robert's answer.